# Using HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo or getRequestURI for matching routes in a Router

Tags: java, mvc, url-routing

I'm currently writing on a Router for a MVC framework that will be the core part of my application. The Router is implemented as a Servlet to be registered on any embedded servlet container. In the Router I'm matching the route using the URI given by `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo` but later I'm registering the route into a central path registry so that every part of the application can find a route by matching a uri, but the problem here is that the Router is aware of the Context Path and `getPathInfo` already hides the Context Path. But the Path Registry is not aware of the context paths and any other part of the application might get into problems when trying to match a uri with Context Path. So, I'm thinking if it might be a better idea to use `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI`.

The Routers important source code:

```java
/**
     * Main method for the Router to be called when a route is accessed
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ServletException 
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String url = req.getPathInfo();
        List<String> acceptHeaders = StringUtil.parseAcceptHeader(req.getHeader("Accept") == null ? "" : req.getHeader("Accept"));
        
        Route route = null;
        RouteQuery query = RouteQuery.of(url).method(req.getMethod()).accepts(req.getContentType());
        
        if(!acceptHeaders.isEmpty()) {
            for(String acceptHeader : acceptHeaders) {
                query.produces(acceptHeader);
                
                route = this.getRouteByURL(query);
                
                if(route != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            route = this.getRouteByURL(query);
        }
        
        if(route == null) {
            String failureReason = this.getFailureReason(query);
            
            switch(failureReason) {
                case "URL_NOT_MATCHING":
                    res.sendError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND_404, "The request url <b>" + req.getRequestURI() + "</b> was not found.");
                    return;
                case "METHOD_NOT_MATCHING":
                    res.sendError(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED_405, "The method " + query.method() + " is not allowed for the path <b>" + req.getRequestURI() + "</b>.");
                    return;
                case "PRODUCES_NOT_MATCHING":
                    res.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST_400, "The Accept-Headers are not allowed for <b>" + req.getRequestURI() + "</b>.");
                    return;
                case "ACCEPTS_NOT_MATCHING":
                    res.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST_400, "Request Content-Type is not allowed");
                    return;
                default:
                    res.sendError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_500, "Unknown error occured while searching routes");
                    return;
            }
        }
        
        Map<RequestParameter, String> params = this.pathResolver.resolvePathParameters(
                route.getCompiledPathSpec(), 
                route.getParameters().keySet().toArray(new RequestParameter[route.getParameters().size()]), 
                url);
        
        try {
            Result result = route.execute(req, res, params);
            
            if(result.redirect().isPresent()) {
                res.sendRedirect(result.redirect().get());
                return;
            }
            
            if(result.status() > 399) {
                if(result.statusMessage().isPresent()) {
                    res.sendError(result.status(), result.statusMessage().get());
                } else {
                    res.sendError(result.status());
                }
                
                return;
            }
            
            if(result.contentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/json")) {
                result.content(NightWeb.getGson().toJson(result.data()));
            }
            
            res.setStatus(result.status());
            res.setContentType(result.contentType());
            res.setCharacterEncoding(result.characterEncoding());
            res.getWriter().write(result.content());
            
            result.cookies().forEach(cookie -> res.addCookie(cookie));
            result.headers().forEach((name, value) -> res.addHeader(name, value));
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            if(e.getCause() instanceof IllegalAccessException) {
                InvokedRoute invokedRoute = (InvokedRoute) route;
                
                LOGGER.error("Unable to access method " + route.getController().getClass().getCanonicalName() + "." + invokedRoute.getUnderlyingMethodName() + " - maybe it is private or not exported?");
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void addRoute(Method method, Controller controller) {
        MethodHolder holder = new MethodHolder(this.ctx, method, controller);
        
        Path pathAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Path.class);
        if(pathAnnotation == null) {
            LOGGER.debug("path annotation not present on " 
                    + method.getName() 
                    + "(" + String.join(",", Arrays.stream(method.getParameters()).map(param -> param.getType().getName() + " " + param.getName()).toArray(String[]::new)));
            return;
        }
        
        Path controllerPath = controller.getClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
        
        holder.setPathSpec(StringUtil.filterURL((controllerPath == null ? "" : controllerPath.value()) + pathAnnotation.value()));
        holder.setCompiledPathSpec(this.pathResolver.compilePathSpec(pathAnnotation.value()));
        
        dev.teamnight.nightweb.core.mvc.annotations.Method methodAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(dev.teamnight.nightweb.core.mvc.annotations.Method.class);
        if(methodAnnotation != null) {
            holder.setHttpMethod(methodAnnotation.value());
        }
        
        if(holder.getHttpMethod() == null) {
            GET getAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(GET.class);
            
            if(getAnnotation != null) {
                holder.setHttpMethod("GET");
            } else {
                POST postAnnoation = method.getAnnotation(POST.class);
                
                if(postAnnoation != null) {
                    holder.setHttpMethod("POST");
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no GET, POST or Method annotation present on " + method.toGenericString());
                }
            }
        }
        
        Accepts acceptsAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Accepts.class);
        if(acceptsAnnotation != null) {
            holder.setAccepts(acceptsAnnotation.value());
        }
        
        Produces producesAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Produces.class);
        if(producesAnnotation != null) {
            holder.setProduces(producesAnnotation.value());
        }
        
        Map<RequestParameter, Integer> parametersMap = new HashMap<RequestParameter, Integer>();
        
        int i = 0;
        for(Parameter param : method.getParameters()) {
            if(param.getType() == HttpServletRequest.class) {
                holder.setPosReq(i++);
                continue;
            } else if(param.getType() == HttpServletResponse.class) {
                holder.setPosRes(i++);
                continue;
            } else if(Context.class.isAssignableFrom(param.getType())) {
                holder.setPosCtx(i++);
                continue;
            } else if(param.getType() == Map.class) {
                holder.setPosParamMap(i++);
                continue;
            }
            
            PathParam pathParam = param.getAnnotation(PathParam.class);
            if(pathParam != null) {
                parametersMap.put(new RequestParameter(true, pathParam.value()), i++);
                continue;
            }
            
            QueryParam queryParam = param.getAnnotation(QueryParam.class);
            if(queryParam != null) {
                parametersMap.put(new RequestParameter(false, queryParam.value()), i++);
            }
            
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Method has unallowed parameter " + param.getName());
        }
        
        holder.setParameters(parametersMap);
        
        this.addRoute(holder);
    }

@Override
    public Route getRouteByURL(RouteQuery query) {
        return this.routes.stream()
                .filter(h -> h.getCompiledPathSpec().matcher(query.url()).matches())
                .filter(h -> h.getHttpMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(query.method()))
                .filter(h -> {
                    if(query.produces().isPresent()) {
                        return h.getProduces().equalsIgnoreCase(query.produces().get());
                    } else {
                        return h.getProduces().equalsIgnoreCase("text/html");
                    }
                })
                .filter(h -> {
                    if(h.getAccepts().isPresent()) {
                        if(query.accepts().isPresent()) {
                            return query.accepts().get().equalsIgnoreCase(h.getAccepts().get());
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

The interface of the Path Registry, as I did not implement it yet, thinking of the problem above:

```java
    /**
     * Matches a route using a given request uri.
     * 
     * @param uri the URI
     * @return {@link dev.teamnight.nightweb.core.mvc.Route} the route or {@code null}
     */
    public Route matchRoute(String uri);
```

The code is also accessible at GitHub, if you need this to answer my question https://github.com/TeamNight/NightWeb/blob/master/NightWeb-Core/src/main/java/dev/teamnight/nightweb/core/impl/ServletRouterImpl.java

Thanks for helping